# Make DOS-Games and DOS-Applications as Bootable?

Tags: boot, ms-dos

How can I make a bootable .iso file and burn it to CD/DVD to run DOS games and DOS programs from that CD/DVD?

I'm making a bootable project that I include some bootable utilities, anti-viruses and some DOS games in it.

So I think the best way to do this is to make a .ISO bootable file that can start DOS games and applications and then include it in my project.

Comment: Is your question how to add games to an existing ISO, or how to make a bootable DOS ISO?

Comment: i just want to add DOS games to an ISO file that i can boot from this iso and play games without any issues

Comment: You didn't answer the question properly. You're creating a bootable project. What is the bootable ISO that you're creating booting into? DOS? BartPE? WinPE? Linux?

Comment: I'm using SARDU to make my All-in-One project ! i added some anti-viruses and windowsPE and etc (This big iso name is: A.iso). NOW i just want to know what can i do to make another ISO image for running DOS based applications and games (This ISO name: B.iso) ?  so i just want to make B.iso ! if i make it, i can incloud it to A.iso (which is my all-in-one). so i can run anythings i added to A.iso (also my B.iso) from just ONE CD/DVD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a bootable DOS ISO:

1. Download or create a bootable DOS floppy .IMG/.IMA image (you can use MS-DOS, FreeDOS etc.)
2. Use something like **UltraISO** to create the ISO. In UltraISO create a new empty image, then go to `Bootable / Load Boot File` and load the bootable DOS floppy image:

   [image: 1]
3. Add installed games to the ISO.
4. Burn and test ISO.

Easier still would be to use a USB stick, since the games might want to write something to disk and would fail to do so when run from a DVD. For this there are plenty of options. **Rufus** includes FreeDOS, so it's as easy as selecting the appropriate option and preparing a DOS bootable USB stick:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you. i'll test it and tell you the result. but there is a question; What different there is between MS-DOS and FreeDOS and PC-DOS? what features they have or they don't have? why nobody don't use a common DOS ?

Comment: There are lots of varieties of DOS, but no such thing as "common DOS". The three you mentioned are versions of DOS from different sources/companies. You can read their Wikipedia articles for more info.

Comment: Do you think, can i use this MS-DOS Based Bootable? (and then add my files and ...) [Ms-Dos v6.22 Bootable Cd Image With Cd-ROM, Mouse and etc](http://www.4shared.com/file/Vg6xU_S6/) ,   will this article works?:  [Hiren's CD: Creat MS-DOS Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootablecd). or anythings you test it before ?

Comment: I don't know about that 4shared link, and am not interested in downloading unknown files from file sharing sites. You can get MS-DOS floppy images from [here](http://www.allbootdisks.com/download/dos.html). That Hiren's page also should help you do what you want. Build-ISO.cmd uses bfi.exe to first create a bootable Floppy.ima image (which you could as well download directly), and then mkisofs.exe is used to create BootCD.iso using the Floppy.ima created in the first step. So basically mkisofs.exe is doing what I told you to use UltraISO for.

Comment: Another useful site: http://www.bootdisk.com